# Field level permissions for users

Tags: strapi

We now have field level permissions for CMS users (content creators) but is there a way to add field level permissions for the API. Restrict certain fields in Collection types or Component to certain end user roles?

### I want to achieve this:

```
const Article = {
  preview: 'Hello this is a .....", // Public ',
  body: 'Only paid users of a certain role can see this text', // Authenticated with Role: Subscriber
};
```

#### For example:

A user with role Subscriber, will see this:

```
const Article = {
  preview: 'Hello this is a .....", // Public ',
  body: 'Only paid users of a certain role can see this text', // Authenticated with Role: Subscriber
};
```

And everyone who hasnt that role see this:

```
const Article = {
  preview: 'Hello this is a .....", // Public ',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I implemented something similar for my content survey (in the controller) where I do not want unauthenticated people to see certain fields (relations in particular), that is why I delete these fields :)

Let me know if the code is helpful or if you need more information.

Good luck!

```
  async findOne(ctx) {
    const { id } = ctx.params;
    const { user } = ctx.state;
(...)
    const entity = await strapi.services.survey.findOne({ id });
    let survey = sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models.survey })
    if ((user == null) || (user.id != survey.users_permissions_user.id)) {
      delete survey.users_permissions_user;
      delete survey.interviewees;
    }
    return survey
  },
};
```